# How to create Product list widget with owl carousel on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, widgets, requirejs

My steps:

1. Copy `magento-2-directory/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/**grid.phtml**` to `magento-2-directory/app/design/frontend/Agestor/default/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/**grid.phtml**`
   [image: Directory]
2. Create `requirejs-config.js` to `magento-2-directory/app/design/frontend/Agestor/default`.
   [image: requirejs-config.js]
3. Widjet not work and I have errors in consol.[image: Widjet]
   [image: Errors]

Comment: Guys, any tips please. Not cool, when use widgets without carousel.

Answer (score 2):

You have to just create requirejs-config.js at below location with code,

**magento-2-directory/app/design/frontend/Agestor/default/Magento_CatalogWidget/requirejs-config.js**

```
/**
 *  This is used for slider
 */
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "js/owl.carousel.min"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command and remove cache.

Comment: Thank you! But I have connection this js with theme. I have same requirejs-config.js in magento-2-directory/app/design/frontend/Agestor/default.

Comment: you can create  file inside above locatino and you can use in your template.

Comment: On foto you can see path for requirejs-config.js. This file works with my theme.

Comment: You can change just content of your requirejs file at your theme file and chekc

Comment: But you write same code, what do I use to connect owl.carousel.min.

Comment: Your code in template file is right just you have to update requirejs config.js base theme file code with same as above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52057/discussion-between-sergey-eremin-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 1):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vender\modulename\Block\Product" name="Custome.product" before="-" template="vender_module::product/custom-list.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="custome.top" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist"
                           name="custome.top" as="wishlist" before="compare"
                           template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml"/>    
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="custome.comapre.top" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.top" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml">

                </block>
            </block> 
        </block>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>


Vender\modulename\Block\Produc extend \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

and use magento/  module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product list.phtml 

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','slickslider'], function (jQuery) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.basic-regular').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
                    infinite: false,
                    slidesToShow: 4 ,
                    slidesToScroll: 2 
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this not answer. You try use slickslider with widget on Magento 2?

Comment: Without widget i did that using phtml file. see screeshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a3686bkdd

Comment: Can you write instruction in answer please?

Comment: mail me on saurabh.jain929@gmail.com, i will send you full code package.  you can use list.phtml html code into your custom template.